# How can I receive "char *d" from DLL in VBA(Excel Visual Basic)?

Tags: c, vba, excel, dll

Now I'm trying to get a char string as the below c function.

This is a C function of DLL,

```
char _stdcall *fmt_hex(long long num, int nbits, char *d)
{
    sprintf(d, "0x%0*llX", (nbits - 1) / 4 + 1, num);
    return (d);
}
```

and the below is the Excel VBA function.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function pll_dll Lib "F:\work\pll_dll\x64\Debug\pll_dll.dll" (ByVal num As LongLong, ByVal nbits As Integer, ByRef d As String)

Dim d As String

Sub useSquareInVBA()
    
    Cells(4, 4).Text = pll_dll(3, 4, d)

End Sub
```

but I've got a program halt when I run this code.
Can you give me what am I supposed to do to resolve this problem?

## Update2

When I ran with this code
"C"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double _stdcall pll_dll(double* datain0, double* datain1, double* dataout0, double* dataout1,  char * str)
{
    dataout0[0] = datain0[0] + 10;
    dataout1[0] = datain1[0] + 10;
    
    str ="c";
    
    return 0;
}
```

"VBA"

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function pll_dll Lib "F:\work\pll_dll\x64\Debug\pll_dll.dll" _
(ByRef x_in As Double, ByRef y_in As Double, ByRef x_out As Double, ByRef y_out As Double, ByRef str As String) As Double

Dim Error As Integer

Dim d1 As Double
Dim d2 As Double
Dim d3 As Double
Dim d4 As Double
Dim sometext As String


Function pll_dll_excel(data1 As Double, data2 As Double, data3 As Double, data4 As Double, text As String) As Double

pll_dll_excel = pll_dll(data1, data2, data3, data4, text)
    
End Function

Sub useSquareInVBA()
    MsgBox pll_dll_excel(3, 4, d1, d2, sometext)
    Cells(5, 5).Value = d1
    Cells(6, 6).Value = d2
    Cells(7, 7).Value = sometext
End Sub
```

No, program halt, but sometext is always empty "" value.

Can you  help me please?

## update3

I've checked with the article from here.

[How to return a string of unknown size from DLL to Visual Basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31409006/how-to-return-a-string-of-unknown-size-from-dll-to-visual-basic)

When I follow this article, I realized that is not "C".
How do I make as a "C"?

Comment: It returns a `char`, but you have it declared as returning a `Variant`.

Comment: Also, who is responsible for the memory allocation for `d`?  Right now, *neither* of them is.

Comment: Neither the C code or the VBA code is allocating any memory.  You're passing a pointer to a null string from VBA and then immediately passing that to `sprintf`.  Your "program halt" is most likely a segfault. Either the C function needs to provide a buffer (an a way for the caller to release it) *or* it needs to be able to communicate *how large* of a buffer the caller needs to create. If you're attached to the interface, consider using `snprintf` and have the VBA code pass the buffer length instead.

Comment: TBH, the C function is fairly trivial to convert to VBA.  I'd do that.

Comment: Does anyone know what am I supposed to do this issue?

Comment: I agree that the function seems fairly easy to convert to VBA but it might not be about the actual functionality of the function itself.  They might be using a simple example to figure out how to link the C function to VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue and this post is the most relevant search result.

Instead of giving a direct solution to the question (credit to [GSerg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11683/gserg) for bringing out the correct approach), am posting a generic version of how I achieved receiving char array passed as reference:

C function (shared library):

```
int func(int a, double b, char *result) {
    ...
    result[0] = 'A';
    result[1] = 'B';
    result[2] = '\0';
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

VBA:

```
Option Explicit

' Import DLL function
Private Declare PtrSafe Function func Lib "C:\path\to\c-shared-library.dll" _
    (ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Double, ByVal result As String) As Integer

' Functions for use by Excel - DLL functions cannot be directly used
Function getResult(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Double) As String
    Dim status As Integer
    Dim result As String
    result = Space$(2)
    status = func(a, b, result)
    If status = 0 Then getResult = result Else Err.Raise 1000, "Error", "Failed to get result"
End Function
```

In my case the result are always going to be a two char array, but I think the above methodology can be accordingly modified.

Comment: No, this is not how you handle `char*` in VB6. The question the OP is linking to [explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31409244/11683) it correctly. You are supposed to allocate the buffer on the VB side and tell the function the size of it. And the `result` would then be declared `ByVal result As String`. Yes, `ByVal`.

Comment: The question is specifically about VBA & NOT VB6 - the question itself says in title 'DLL in VBA(Excel Visual Basic)' & similarly mentions 'Excel VBA' in the question.... Please read the original question.

Comment: The only difference between VBA and VB6 in `Declare` statements is that VBA supports [`PtrSafe`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44785205/11683) starting from VBA7, and VB6 does not. Everything else, including the handling of strings, is identical.

Comment: The referred [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31409244/11683) didn't work for me and this is the only one which worked somehow...

Comment: Still, the referred approach is absolutely correct. You declare a string in VB, you assign some space to it with `Space$(128)`, you pass it to C++ telling it how long it currently is, and you declare that string `ByVal`. Every step is important. If you don't assign the `Space$`, you will crash on writing into wrong memory. If you don't provide the correct length, you will crash on writing into wrong memory. If by declare the argument `ByRef`, you will crash on the attempt of the runtime to make a `BSTR` out of it. You might have missed one step, so you could ask a separate question about it.

Comment: In the code above, you are effectively trying to do the marshaller's job manually, with the added inconvenience of `func` not knowing how large the buffer is.

Comment: Okay.... Yes I got that working now. Will update the answer...