# 32bit vs 64bit Office - Ptrsafe function delcaration - when can I use it

Tags: vba

We are moving from 32-bit to 64-bit Office products. This means that some of the VBA code throws errors if the function is not declared `PtrSafe`. I understand that I can use Ptrsafe in combination with `#If VBA7...`

My question is, can I declare all functions `PtrSafe` or there are functions that would not work or cause error?

Thank you for your response, have a nice day

Comment: You may find this info helpful: [APY declarations - 32 and 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/10569/api-calls/31727/windows-api-dedicated-module-1-of-2#t=201706271443596300067)

Answer (score 1):

`PtrSafe` does not introduce any functionality. You cannot therefore say that something will or will not without it.

`PtrSafe` is a flag with which you tell to the compiler, "I have verified that types I used for this API declaration are correct regardless of the pointer size".

If you have verified that the types you are using are correct, put the `PtrSafe`. If you haven't, don't put it (and then it will not compile when there is a possibility of an error, that is, when the pointer size is not 32 bits).