# How can I convert my VBA program to 64 bit

Tags: vba, 32bit-64bit

How can I convert the below program to 64 bit?

```
Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" _
  (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, _
    ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, _
     ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long

Declare Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "kernel32" _
  (ByVal L_Prozess As Long, _
    l_Ende As Long) As Long

Declare Sub Sleep Lib "Kernel32.dll" _
  (ByVal SleepTime As Long)
```

Comment: Welcome Sudhanshu! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow and earn your first badge. We're a little bit different from other sites. Here's how...  https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: What problems are you specifically having?

Answer (score 4):

My advice was always to use the excellent free tool ["Windows API Viewer"](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/dennis/windowsapiviewer.htm) that was hosted on Ron de Bruins web page, however, the link is currently pointing to a 404, don't know why. You can still find it using the [way back machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20200701025741/http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/dennis/windowsapiviewer.htm). Note that there are some AV scanners that don't like the tool and mark it as potentially harmful, however from all I know this is a false alert - I have been using that tool for a long time and never had issues.

The output of that tool gave me the following declarations. Note that they are not tested (except for `Sleep`)

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" Alias "OpenProcess" _
                            (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, _
                             ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, _
                             ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As LongPtr
    Declare PtrSafe Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetExitCodeProcess" _
                            (ByVal hProcess As LongPtr, _
                             lpExitCode As Long) As Long
    Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" Alias "Sleep" _
                            (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#Else
    ' (This is your code)
    Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" _
                            (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, _
                             ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, _
                             ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long
Declare Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "kernel32" _
                            (ByVal L_Prozess As Long, _
                             l_Ende As Long) As Long
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "Kernel32.dll" _
                            (ByVal SleepTime As Long)
#End If
```

Comment: `Note that they are not tested` - the `#If Win64` [should be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56940710/11683) `#If VBA7`, otherwise this is correct.

Comment: @GSerg: You are right - I always confuse the meaning of those. I will correct my answer.