# Understanding VBByRefStr in VB.NET P/Invoke declarations

Tags: .net, vb.net, pinvoke, marshalling

When trying to use a P/Invoke declaration made in a VB.NET assembly from C# I noticed that `string` arguments become `ref string` arguments.

A closer inspection reveals that e.g.

```vb
Public Declare Unicode Function RegDeleteValue Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "RegDeleteValueW" ( _
ByVal hKey As IntPtr, ByVal lpValueName As String) As UInteger
```

is compiled to

```cs
[DllImport(...)]public static extern uint RegDeleteValue(
    IntPtr hKey, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.VBByRefStr)] ref string lpValueName);
```

On [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-strings#strings-used-in-platform-invoke) I read:

> `VBByRefStr`: A value that enables Visual Basic .NET to change a string in unmanaged code, and have the results reflected in managed code. This value is supported only for platform invoke. This is default value in Visual Basic for `ByVal` strings.

I still don't get it. Why is it only `string lpValueName` in C# (see [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.RegDeleteKey) *- edit:* for [`RegDeleteKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regdeletekeya) as Damien_The_Unbeliever pointed out, signature is the same like [`RegDeleteValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regdeletevaluea)) but strange `VBByRefStr` in VB.NET? Should I declare with `<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)>` in VB.NET to avoid `ref` in C#? Or does that have any adverse effects?

Comment: Not that it makes a great deal of different but your pinvoke link is to a *different* function. `RegDeleteKey` != `RegDeleteValue`. I can't find a PInvoke page for [`RegDeleteValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724851(v=vs.85).aspx) in advapi32

Comment: My bad, looks like I ended up with `RegDeleteKey` on pinvoke when I did not find `RegDeleteValue`. Sorry for the confusion. However, the main observation is the same with `RegDeleteKey` too :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is for backwards compatibility with VB6 Declare statements.

When using ByVal x As String, you indicated that you wanted to convert the VB UTF-16 "String" type into an ASCII representation, pass a pointer to that ASCII buffer to that parameter, and after the call had succeeded, convert the contents of that buffer back into the original UTF-16 string.

This has subsequently been enhanced in VB.NET to support Unicode API calls. However, I would imagine that the VBByRefStr constant indicates that the marshalling done in .NET must follow the method in VB6 exactly.

If you want the standard marshalling for UnmanagedType.LPWStr, then use  attributes.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for explaining! I guess I should get rid of the VB6-style `Declare` statements overall and use `DllImport` instead