# Unhandled delphi exception in 3rd party dll

Tags: delphi, go, dll, interop, pinvoke

I have a dynamic library from which I need to call a procedure in my Go program, but I can't seem to get it right. I have another program written in C# which uses this DLL and according to dnSpy dllimport compiles to:

```
[DllImport("Library.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern void Calc(double[] Input, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.VBByRefStr)] ref string Pattern, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.VBByRefStr)] ref string Database_path, double[] Output);
```

So basing on this I tried to call it in my code like so:

```
func main() {
    lib := syscall.NewLazyDLL("Library.dll")
    proc := lib.NewProc("Calc")

    input := [28]float64{0.741, 0.585, 2, 12, 1, 1, 1, 101325, 2500, 3, 20, 17.73, 17.11, 45, 1, 0, 80, 60, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0}
    output := [20]float64{}
    tubePattern := marshalAnsi("P8-16G-E145/028")
    basePath, _ := filepath.Abs(".")
    databasePath := marshalAnsi(basePath)
    a1 := uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&input))
    a2 := uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(tubePattern))
    a3 := uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(databasePath))
    a4 := uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&output))
    ret, _, _ := proc.Call(a1, a2, a3, a4)
    log.Println(ret)
    log.Println(output)
}

func marshalAnsi(input string) *[]byte {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    writer := transform.NewWriter(&b, charmap.Windows1252.NewEncoder())
    writer.Write([]byte(input))
    writer.Close()
    output := b.Bytes()
    return &output
}
```

This results in unhandled delphi exception:

```
Exception 0xeedfade 0x31392774 0x32db04e4 0x7677ddc2
PC=0x7677ddc2

syscall.Syscall6(0x314af7d0, 0x4, 0x10ee7eb8, 0x10ed21a0, 0x10ed21d0, 0x10ee7d78, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
        C:/Go32/src/runtime/syscall_windows.go:184 +0xcf
syscall.(*Proc).Call(0x10ed21e0, 0x10ed85e0, 0x4, 0x4, 0x10, 0x49bee0, 0x533801, 0x10ed85e0)
        C:/Go32/src/syscall/dll_windows.go:152 +0x32e
syscall.(*LazyProc).Call(0x10ecb9c0, 0x10ed85e0, 0x4, 0x4, 0x0, 0x0, 0x4c6d70, 0x5491a0)
        C:/Go32/src/syscall/dll_windows.go:302 +0x48
main.main()
        C:/Users/Krzysztof Kowalczyk/go/src/danpoltherm.pl/dllloader/main.go:32 +0x2c0
eax     0x19f3f0
ebx     0x31392774
ecx     0x7
edx     0x0
edi     0x10ee7d78
esi     0x31392774
ebp     0x19f448
esp     0x19f3f0
eip     0x7677ddc2
eflags  0x216
cs      0x23
fs      0x53
gs      0x2b
```

I believe that problem might lie in the way I pass these strings to procedure, but I can't see what my code does different than that C# application.

Library have a few other procedures, I can call `DLL_Version` with no problems like so:

```
lib := syscall.NewLazyDLL("Library.dll")
verProc := lib.NewProc("DLL_Version")
var version float64
verProc.Call(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&version)))
log.Printf("DLL version: %f\n", version)
```

Outputs:

```
2018/09/10 09:13:11 DLL version: 1.250000
```

EDIT:
I believe that I found out what causes the exception. It seems that when called from my code, 2nd and 3rd parameters for this procedure, which should be pointers to string buffers, are instead pointers to pointers on these buffers, if I break on the beginning of procedure and patch this manually, code runs and terminates correctly. I still did not found a reason why this happens, and how to fix it though.

EDIT2:
Apparently my previous assessment of this case was invalid. I was able to stop program from throwing exception, but I analyzed assembly and it turned out it was only due to program exiting before this exception was thrown, and instead of exception I got normal error code about invalid string.

While I'm not really good at understanding disassembled code, it seems that problem might indeed be caused by calling convention mismatch. At the beginning of procedure code, when called from working program EAX, EBX, ECX and EDX registers are empty, meanwhile when called from my code, only EAX and ECX are empty, EDX holds something but EBX points to Calc procedure pointer in my executable. Later in the DLL there is a part which checks if EBX is empty and throws exception if not.

EDIT 3:
Well, that seems to also be unrelated, I'm aware that there is too little information for anyone to be able to make any guess as to what is going on. So I'll try to track where this exception comes from exactly and come back to this question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43385670/understanding-vbbyrefstr-in-vb-net-p-invoke-declarations  Also, how in the go code are you handling the fact that the function has `void` return type? And how do you know that the two double arrays are long enough?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Strings in go are utf-8 encoded, so I manually convert it to Windows-1251 manually and pass pointer to byte array as parameter to procedure. I'm not sure what is there to handle with `void` type return. I do have documentation for this dll, so I know what size of arrays I need, but it does not specify format of strings.

Comment: The C# pinvoke specifies the ABI for the function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I've finally found an answer. As @kostix noticed `go-ole` was required, since DLL uses COM and I had to call CoInitializeEx first.

But that was only part of this, turns out string parameters of procedure were declared as UnicodeString, which required me to put together a conversion function to properly fit into layout described in documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Unicode_in_RAD_Studio#New_String_Type:_UnicodeString

And once that was done, all started to work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

You're consistently making a rather common error: taking a pointer to a Go string or slice. The problem with this is that both slices and strings
[are in fact `struct`s](https://blog.golang.org/slices)—of three and two fields, correspondingly. Hence when you're taking an address of a variable containing a slice or a string, that's an address of the first field of that struct, *not* of the first item contained in the container.

So, the first fix is to replace all places making use of

```
var v []whatever
p := unsafe.Pointer(&v)
```

and

```
var s string
p := unsafe.Pointer(&s)
```

with

```
var v []whatever
p := unsafe.Pointer(&v[0])
```

and

```
var s string
p := unsafe.Pointer(&s[0])
```

correspondingly.

Two more points to consider:

- It's hard for me to figure exact semantics of `VBByRefStr` just by reading a poorly-worded MSDN doc, but from cursory reading of some posts about it I have managed to google, it appears your target function has these parameters typed as `PChar`.

  If I'm correct in my assessment, the strings you pass to the function must be zero-terminated as they are not Delphi-native strings, and have no length field encoded in them.

  Hence when preparing the strings I'd make sure you add the `\x00` character at the end.

  Note that in your example the Go strings are plain ASCII (and note that UTF-8 is ASCII-clean, i.e. UTF-8-encoded strings which contain only 7-bit ASCII characters to not need any re-encoding before passing them to anything which intends to see an ASCII data), and Windows code pages are ASCII-compatible as well. Hence for your case for a start I'd not mess with proper character set conversion and would do something like

  ```
  func toPChar(s string) unsafe.Pointer {
    dst := make([]byte, len(s)+1)
    copy(dst, s)
    dst[len(s)] = 0 // NUL terminator
    return unsafe.Pointer(&dst[0])
  }
  ```

  …and once you make it work with plain ASCII strings, add character conversion in the mix.
- Do not store the result of type-conversion of an `unsafe.Pointer` to `uintptr` in a variable!

  This is a non-obvious thing, I admit, but the logic is as follows:

  - For Go GC, a variable containing a value of type `unsafe.Pointer`constitutes a live reference to the memory it points to (if the value is non-`nil`, of course).
  - The `uintptr` type is specifically defined as representing an *opaque pointer-sized integer* value, not a pointer. Hence an address stored in a variable of type `uintptr` does not count as a live reference to the memory at that address.

These rules mean when you take an address of some variable and store it in a variable of type `uintptr`, it means you may have zero references
to that memory block. For instance, in this example

```
    func getPtr() unsafe.Pointer
    ...
    v := uintptr(getPtr())
```

the GC is free to reclaim the memory a pointer to which was returned by `getPtr()`.

As a special case, Go guarantees that it's OK to use casting of `unsafe.Pointer` to `uintptr` in expressions which are evaluated to produce actual arguments to call a function. So, store intermediate pointers not as `uintptr`s but rather than `unsafe.Pointer`s and cast them at the function call site, like in

```
    a1 := unsafe.Pointer(&whatever[0])
    ...
    ret, _, _ := proc.Call(uintptr(a1), uintptr(a2),
        uintptr(a3), uintptr(a4))
```

It would also be cool to see the actual Delphi-native type of the function you're calling.

---

Another problem might be mismatch in the calling convention but if I understand correctly, P/Invoke defaults to `winapi` CC (which equals `stdcall` on Windows), and since your P/Invoke wrapper does not list any CC explicitly, we may hope it's indeed `winapi` so we should be fine here.

Comment: Thanks for such detailed explanation, I learned a lot from it. Unfortunately it looks like there might be problem with calling convention. I edited my question with more details.

Comment: Are you by chance able to (temporarily) use `cgo` to attempt to call your function? With `cgo`, you should be able to specify the calling convention in the function declaration so that the compiler would arrange to employ proper calling convention. Another possible vector to attack this problem is to try linking this DLL to a Delphi-native test program which would specify different calling convention for that imported function before each compile+run cycle—so that you could figure out which one is correct.

Comment: BTW I would be grateful if you would keep me posted on your progress on this issue (I'm interested in this stuff). ;-)

Comment: I actually gave it a try but ran into problems with linker, somehow my toolchain does not play nicely with 32bit go (Most of libraries I need for this project don't have 64bit versions) I'll try to clean my setup later to make it work. I'm comparing execution of this procedure side by side called from working program and mine. It seems to execute identically up till call to CoCreateInstance in combase library, but I still have to confirm this tomorrow.

Comment: Hmm, may be [`go-ole`](https://github.com/go-ole/go-ole) might come in handy with this?

Comment: I finally found out what caused all this, and posted an answer, `go-ole` did indeed come in handy. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Thanks for keeping me in the loop. Glad you got it sorted!

Comment: (Apologies for my broken edit, not sure what happened there!)