# Calling DLL from VB.net causes heap exception

Tags: c, string, windows, vb.net, dll

I made a DLL with gcc that contains only the following function:

```
#include <windows.h>

BSTR __declspec(dllexport) testfunc(void)
{
     return SysAllocString(L"Hello");
}
```

which is based on the code at the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31409244/1505939). The build command is `gcc -shared -o testfunc.dll main.c -Os -s -loleaut32`.

In Visual Basic using VS 2017 Community my code is:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System
Imports System.Text

Module Module1
    <DllImport("testfunc.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl
               )>
    Private Function testfunc() As String
    End Function

    Sub Main()
    Dim Ret = testfunc()
    Console.WriteLine(Ret)
    End Sub
End Module
```

However, executing the program causes an exception upon returning from `testfunc`. Execution never reaches the `Console.WriteLine` line. The exception is:

```
The program '[15188] ConsoleApp1.exe' has exited with code -1073740940 (0xc0000374).
```

which indicates heap corruption.  What am I doing wrong?

---

Things I tried that didn't help:

- Changing to `__stdcall` and declaring the function with `Declare Auto Function testfunc Lib "testfunc.dll" Alias "testfunc@0" () As String` instead of `<DllImport...>`

Things that did work correctly:

- Changing the function to return an integer; but then I can't access my string of course.

Note: I'm aware that I could try "returning" the string via a `ByRef StringBuilder` parameter as suggested on the thread I linked, but that seems like quite a lot of work on the client end and I would like to make it as simple as possible for the client, i.e. see if I can get this approach working.

Comment: Doesn't the return value need to be marshalled? `<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)> String`

Comment: @Swordfish that gave a return string of only `H`, however if I use `UnmanagedType.Bstr` then it worked correctly. Would you be able to write an answer that I can accept? This syntax wasn't mentioned in any of the pages that came up when I was trying to search this topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for data to be passed between managed and unmanaged code it has to be properly mashalled. Since the runtime can not know what your `testfunc()` returns, you have to tell it by providing a declaration of it, which you did by

```vb
<DllImport("testfunc.dll")>
Private Function testfunc() As String
```

But the information that the return type is a `String` is ambiguous since there are many way of string representation. Use the [MarshalAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2)-Attribute to tell the runtime how to handle the returned value:

```vb
<DllImport("testfunc.dll")>
Private Function testfunc() As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)> String
```

Read more about [Interop Marshaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/04fy9ya1(v%3dvs.90)) and [Passing strings between managed and unmanaged code](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1189085/Passing-strings-between-managed-and-unmanaged-code).

Comment: Further info (?)  I since discovered that using the default marshaler, and also using `CoTaskMemAlloc` instead of `SysAllocString` also worked correctly